# Anonymous arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

What is the utility of anonymous arrays compared to arrays shortcut?
In what scenario anonymous arrays are used?

Comment: passing a parameter to method which accepts an array type.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'arrays shortcut'

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933864/in-java-when-is-the-a-b-c-array-shorthand-inappropriate-and-why

Comment: Many people use different words for different things. It is best to provide a code sample.

Comment: See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274356/anonymous-array-in-java-is-this-an-example-of-one . The term "anonymous array" is not standard, and is misleading. Java arrays don't have names. Zero or more variables may reference an array, and those variables have names.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean anonymous arrays like anonymous class where it was declared and instantiated at the same time without a name. The example below shows when you would use it.

For example, you have a method which expects an array of `int` as the argument in the parameter list.

```
public void fillPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, nPoints)
```

To invoke this method:

```
int[] xPoints = {1,2,3};
int[] yPoints = {4,5,6};
g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
```

You can also write it as:

```
g.fillPolygon(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{4,5,6}, 3);
```

> In what scenario anonymous arrays are used?

**A:** Use it when you are only going to use it *once* because you do not keep a reference (name) for the arrays.

**Q:** So what is the benefit of using "anonymous array"?

**A:** It keeps your codes concise.

Answer (score 3):

Hello imagine that you have the following code:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void printArray(int []arr){
        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

The output is `123456`. If you want to call the printArrayMethod in a single line you have to use a anonymous array like the following:

```
printArray(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

You cant use something like the following:

```
printArray({1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

It is going to provoke a compilation fail.

And the question is, Why do I need to use an anonymous array and not a normal array like the first example.

Check the following code:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void printArray(int []arr){
        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Many code
        printArray(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
        //Many code
    }
}
```

If you use a normal array this array is going to alive in your heap during all the main method execution and with the anonymous array you are only use this array to the printArray method and after this the object is going to be eligible to the garbage collector.