# Why I can't initialize anonymous String array with initial capacity?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I'm trying to create new anonymous String array:

```
 String[] arr= new String[3]{"a", "b", "c"};
```

But IDE gives me compile-time error syntax. This syntax available on some other language, but why Java doesn't allow this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anonymous arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056815/anonymous-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> This syntax available on some other language, but why Java doesn't allow this?

Because it is either redundant or error prone.

- It is redundant if the size of the array and the number of elements in the initializer *must be* the same.
- It is error prone if the size of the array and the number of elements in the initializer *may be* different.  (It is not obvious to the reader whether there are default initialized elements at the end ... unless the reader *counts* the elements by hand.)

This is my opinion.  We don't *know* if the Java language designers used the same reasoning.  Either way, it is moot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `new String[]`, just writing the array elements declares a new array.

```
String[] arr= {"a", "b", "c"};
```