# Java: anonymous Set<T> inside a function call

Tags: java, arrays, methods, hashmap, set

As found in this question [Anonymous arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056815/anonymous-arrays-in-java) I tried the same procedure for a `java.utils.Set`, but it does not work.

If i have

```
private HashMap<String, String[]> flags;
```

I can easily call

```
this.flags.put("test", new String[]{"value"});
```

But with

```
private HashMap<String, Set<String>> flags;
```

this does **not work**:

```
this.flags.put("test", new Set<String>().add("value"));
```

What is the correct way, to pass an anonymous Set into a function in Java?

Comment: `Set.add()` does not return a `Set`. And `Set` is an interface, meaning you can't just instantiate it like that.

Comment: Then is there a possibility without the `.add()` ? – `this.flags.put("test", new Set<String>());` won't compile as well.

Comment: You first need to create a set from a concrete class, like `HashSet`. Then you're putting that set, not the result of `add`. Somethinglike `this.flags.put("test", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("value"));` should work

Comment: Jup, this does compile. Thanks! @ernest_k

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

When first encountered it will add the `HashSet` and add the value.  The next times it is encountered it will add the value to the hashSet.

```
this.flags.computeIfAbsent("test", v-> new HashSet<>()).add("value");
```

Comment: Nuts.  I mis-placed the parens.

Answer (score 1):

## `Set.of`

If you want your new set to be [non-modifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable), and without null values, use [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)).

```
private Map< String , Set< String > > flags = new HashMap<>() ;
…
this.flags.put( "test" , Set.of( "value" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to attempt to add an anonymous Set, then in that case you need to have the complete implementation of you Set as well-

Ex:

```
        HashMap<String, Set<String>> valueMap = new HashMap<>();


        valueMap.put("test", new Set<String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean add(String e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> iterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean remove(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
```

A better  and simple approach would be

```
valueMap.put("test", new HashSet<String>(){{
            add("a");
            add("b");
            add("c");
        }});
```

Comment: Which purpose do these double parentheses `{{` and `}}` serve?

Comment: That is a Double brace initialization. The outer brace is anonymous class creation of HashSet and the second brace is for initialization.

Comment: It's a block initializer.  But this technique is falling out of favor  in the Java community.

Comment: Yes I agree its an expensive operation though

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to create set in anonymous way, rather than you can use some utility methods like [Collections.singleton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-) for java-8 version code, and you can use [Set.of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361818/9959152) for java-9 and above

> an immutable set containing only the specified object.

```
this.flags.put("test", Collections.singleton("value"));
```